# Playing a sound on android

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have come across another error along my first app journey :) I want to play a sound when the app loads. Which is a .wav file. It lasts 2 seconds long yet it does not play when I run the app on my old Samsung S4. There is no errors within the IDE or anything I can see, I have checked if 'mp' has a value and it does. Looking around on posts most people have the problem that 'mp' is = null. Whereas mine has a value just no sound comes out of the phone... Again, any help is appreciated!

```
public class OpeningScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    // create the screen state
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // connect the xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening_screen);

        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.create(this, R.raw.welcome_message);

        mp.start();

        // create the on touch listener
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.opening_layout);

        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // change the screen to a new state
                Intent intent = new Intent(OpeningScreen.this, GameScreen.class);

                // start the new activity
                startActivity(intent);

                // stop welcome sound (if still playing)
                mp.stop();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public static MediaPlayer create(Context context, int resid)` is a static method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id.
It means that by calling create you are creating a new instance of media player with no reference usage.

Try to change

```
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.create(this, R.raw.welcome_message);
```

to

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw. welcome_message);
```

And the player should work.

Comment: That's how I had it first. But mp was still null after passing this line of code.

Comment: I just did it again, and it worked this time. Maybe I messed up on the filename or some sort. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to register for `OnPreapredListener` via `MediaPlayer.setOnPreaparedListener` and after preparation you start your media playback.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use final? 
You can play a mp3 with

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(OpeningScreen.this, R.raw.welcome_message);
mp.start();
```

Also stopping mediaplayer is better if you stop in onDestroy.

```
   public void onDestroy() {

    mp.stop();
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Comment: The final is used so I can 'access mp from within inner class.' Although if i made this function it would have to be outside where `mp` is declared anyway so it would still surely require to be final.